# Unity Raycast not working from close distances

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to have various interactions take place when looking at a game object, but it doesn't seem to work when I'm too close. I'm using Unity's first person controller and the script it attached to the camera.

```
void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,(forward), out hit) ){
        GameObject lookingAt = hit.collider.gameObject;
        if (lookingAt.layer == 9)
        {
            Debug.Log("This doesn't always show up.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) says _Raycasts will not detect Colliders for which the Raycast origin is inside the Collider._ which is likely what is causing your problem. However this is an assumption so you should try it out and report your findings here. Also, you can just use `transform.forward` instead of `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)`.

Comment: Thanks! Hmmm. Is it wrong to put the Raycast script on the First Person Controller? Here's where I've put it: https://imgur.com/a/ftBgnQV

(and thanks for the transform tip)

Comment: That is not wrong, raycasting from the center of camera is a common thing among FPS games, since you want to make sure your crosshair being at the center would actually hit things.

Answer (score 0):

I put

```
public LayerMask interactionLayers = ~0;
```

And selected the elements that should be detected in the inspector. That seemed to fix the issue.

Thanks.